# Unity 5.6.1f1 Dll is not allowed to be included or could not be found

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, dll

After updated Unity to 5.6.1f1 version.

I'm getting the next message while trying to Build and Run on android device:

`ArgumentException: The Assembly UnityEditor is referenced by Assembly-CSharp ('Library/ScriptAssemblies/Assembly-CSharp.dll'). But the dll is not allowed to be included or could not be found.`

`UnityEditor.AssemblyHelper.AddReferencedAssembliesRecurse (System.String assemblyPath, System.Collections.Generic.List1 alreadyFoundAssemblies, System.String[] allAssemblyPaths, System.String[] foldersToSearch, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary2 cache, BuildTarget target) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/AssemblyHelper.cs:142)
UnityEditor.AssemblyHelper.FindAssembliesReferencedBy (System.String[] paths, System.String[] foldersToSearch, BuildTarget target) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/AssemblyHelper.cs:179)
UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()`

I deleted the Temp and Library folders and rebuild the project but the error still happens.

Comment: The dll needs to be in the bin folder of the project.  The compiler will automatically copy dll to proper location if it is included in the project.  So use menu : Project : Add existing item : Browse for dll (set type to executable).  Then recompile.  Then when you compile the dll will be in the bin folder.

Comment: Is one of your Scripts `using UnityEditor;` and not in a folder called `Editor`?

Comment: @Smartis Yes, OVR (Oculus VR) scripts are using. And I'm using them

Comment: @jdweng It helped but returns after few rebuilds, Where should the UnityEditor should sit?

Comment: @David I'm sorry but `UnityEditor` is not allowed for Scripts during runtime. These classes are for the editor-only.

Comment: @Smartis I only imported OVR scripts to my project.